# How to run ReactJS in my Local PC?

Tags: reactjs

Can any tell me how can I run the ReactJS sample in my Local PC which I created in the [`JSFiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/shinoy/74dykyde/) ?

I am really new to ReactJS.

Comment: I've just run through the method in my answer so it should work for you, let me know if not.

Comment: Hi Tom, I am getting Access denied error in IE from Broswer.mini.js

Comment: Hi Shinoy, it won't work with IE (nor Chrome I don't think), but it did work with Firefox for me.  (If you need it to work in IE I think you would need to incorporate the javascript in the same file as the html)

Answer (score 7):

## Updated answer 2019

Things have moved in the three years since I wrote the original answer below.

Facebook now have a great example of adding [React to an existing site](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html) which is probably the easiest way to get React up and running if you have some basic web experience.

There's also a frequently updated and very well maintained [official Facebook React starter kit](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) that's another excellent starting point.

### Original Answer 2016

There are two quick approaches:

#### Use the Starter Kit

The [official facebook documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html) provides a Starter Kit that you can download and then all you have to do is:

1. Unzip the starter kit
2. Add a `helloworld.html` file in the root directory of the unzipped starter kit (the root directory is the one that contains the build and examples folders)
3. Edit that html file, remove the existing react component in the file, and then add any necessary bits of html from your fiddle
4. Add a new folder in the root directory called `src`
5. Add a new file in the src directory called `helloworld.js`
6. Copy the js from your fiddle into that file
7. Add a script tag pointing at your js file in your helloworld.html file: `<script type="text/babel" src="src/helloworld.js"></script>`

After you've done that your files should look like this:

helloworld.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello React!</title>
    <script src="build/react.js"></script>
    <script src="build/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="src/helloworld.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

src\helloworld.js

```
var H = React.createClass({

    getInitialState:function(){
        return{count:0}
    },

    increment:function(){
        this.setState({count:this.state.count+1});
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <button onClick={this.increment}>I have been clicked {this.state.count}times!</button>
        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
<H />,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

#### View it in a browser

Then, open up the helloworld.html file in a browser.  Internet Explorer wouldn't open it for me and the docs say Chrome may not like the separate js file, I had to use Firefox.  I just right clicked the file and picked open with Firefox.  The URL should look something like `file:///C:/Users/Tom/Downloads/react-0.14.6/react-0.14.6/helloworld.html`

#### Use NPM

Alternatively, if your comfy with node and npm then [that page](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html) also gives all the instructions needed for getting React up and running from npm.

Answer (score 0):

First you'll need some type of IDE (e.g. Atom, Sublime, Cloud9, etc.); this is your code editor much like what JSFiddle provides. From there, the easiest way to get things running is to run a development server locally using nodejs. Here is a starter kit that has tons of great features for development: https://github.com/RickWong/react-isomorphic-starterkit

Answer (score 0):

[Create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) will help you create a project with react shortly

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```